# What's the nutella for?

Tags: captain-america, iron-man, marvel, science

In the image below, Captain America is hugging the Winter Soldier while telling Stark and Banner

> ... I have my own secret club now

Cap's club is *Army Bros* so I'm assuming that implies Stark and Banner are *Science Bros*?

Stark has a bottle of coke and some mentos. So you dump the mentos in the coke and you get a reaction, we've all seen / done that.

Banner has some nutella.

What's the nutella for?

Is there some viral science experiment involving nutella and I've just never heard of it?

Or is there some canon reason Bruce is holding the nutella?

Banner really likes hazelnut sandwich spread?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's probably a reference [to this excitable fellow](http://knowyourmeme.com/videos/85289-diet-coke-and-mentos)<sup>1</sup>:

I have absolutely no idea what he's saying, but he combines Coca-Cola, Mentos and Nutella to fill a Durex condom to absurd proportions, and is really happy about it.

According to our friends at [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42457/23963), the Nutella doesn't actually add anything to the reaction, from a chemical perspective. If there was any logical sense behind its use, it would have been as a delivery method only; to make sure that all of the Mentos tablets got into the coke all at once.

Here's an video of someone else (speaking in English) doing the same thing:

---

<sup>1</sup> Do ***not*** watch this video in a public place without headphones on (or the sound turned way down); he gets very, very excited when his <s>abomination</s> experiment (literally) blows up in his face

Comment: And that would also explain the small green object on the table 

Comment: @Daft Indeed, though with Tony that one's par for the course

Comment: Remember girls, the next time a guy says he's too big for a rubber send him the crazy Italian... he's so happy...